# VSCode remote-ssh cant connect to win server 2019

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-remote

I'm using VSCode remote-ssh extension for development on winserv2016 and it works as intended. We recently switched to winserv2019 and the extension does not work. the error I get in output is

```
    Server failed to start. - Program 'icacls.exe' failed to run: Win32 internal err
> or "Access is denied" 0x5 occurred while reading the console output buffer. Cont
> act Microsoft Customer Support Services.At line:4 char:1
> + icacls $ai_ /reset /Q
```

I have and admin rights on this machine, does anyone encounter this issue? I've also tried nightly build of VScode and nightly extension. No Success so far.